# Screen issue: getpwuid can't identify your account

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen, embedded-linux

I am trying to run the static binary `screen`. I have created `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`. When I did `ls -la /etc/passwd /etc/group` I didn't get any errors, but when I am trying to run `./screen` I get:

```
Getpwuid() can't identify your account!
```

This is on embedded Linux. My bin folder is under the path `/system/bin`

How can I fix "Getpwuid() can't identify your account!" issue of the screen binary?

This is the result of the `strace /screen`:
[image]